# Linearizing the Lugiato-Lefever Partial Differential Equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, linearized-theory, non-linear-schroedinger

> **Problem Statement:**
>   Given the Lugiato-Lefever equation, linearize the equation and determine the dynamics near a stationary solution by looking for a stationary solution with a small perturbation.
>
> **Relevant Equations:**
>   The  Lugiato-Lefever Equation is given by:
>   $$ \frac {d\psi} {dt} = -(1 + i \alpha)\psi + \frac {i} {2} \frac {d^2\psi} {dx^2} + i * \psi^2 \bar \psi + F. $$
>
> It can be shown that when looking for stationary solutions in both time and space, the following is a solution:
>   $$ \psi_e = \frac F  {1 + i * (\alpha - \rho)} $$
>   When $\rho$ is the solution of the polynomial:
>   $$ F ^ 2 = (1 + (\rho - \alpha) ^ 2)\rho .$$

**Attempt at a solution:**
I started by substituting the following ansatz:

$$ \psi = \psi_e + \psi_1  $$

When $ |\psi_1| \ll 1 $. Substituting the above into the equation yields:

$$ \frac {d\psi_1} {dt} = -(1 + i\alpha)\psi_1 + \frac i 2 \frac {\partial ^ 2 \psi _1 } {\partial x ^ 2 }  + i (\bar \psi_1 \psi_1 ^2 + \bar \psi_e \psi _1 ^2 + 2\bar\psi_e \psi_e \psi_1 + \bar \psi_1 \psi_e ^2 + 2\bar\psi_1 \psi_e \psi_1) $$

I am interested in a first order treatment, so i will take out the terms quadratic in $\psi_1$:

$$ \frac {d\psi_1} {dt} = -(1 + i\alpha)\psi_1 + \frac i 2 \frac {\partial ^ 2 \psi _1 } {\partial x ^ 2 }  + i ( 2\bar\psi_e \psi_e \psi_1 + \bar \psi_1 \psi_e ^2) $$

I know $\psi_e$ as it is the stationary solution from above, and for $\psi_1$ I can look for solutions of the form:

$$ \psi_1 = e^{i\omega t}*(a * e^{ikx} + \bar b * e^{-ikx})$$

After doing that and equating the coefficients of the backwards and forwards propagating plane waves, I arrived at the following equations:

$$ i\omega \bar b = \bar b (-(1+i\alpha) - \frac i 2 k^2 + i2\bar\psi_e\psi_e) + \bar a (i\bar\psi_1\psi_e^2) $$

$$ i\omega a = a(-(1+i\alpha) - \frac i 2 k^2 + i2\bar\psi_e\psi_e) + b(i\bar\psi_`1\psi_e^2) $$

This is almost what I wanted, but the first equation is on the conjugates of a and b rather than on a and b so I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the last step of "equating the coefficients of the backwards and forwards propegating waves". After equating the coefficients, one should arrive at the following system:
$$ i\omega a = a[-(1+i\alpha) - \frac{i}{2}k^2 + 2i|\psi_e|^2] + b[i\psi_e^2] $$
$$ i\omega b = a[-i\bar{\psi_e}] + b[-(1-i\alpha)+\frac{i}{2}k^2-2i|{\psi_e}|^2] $$

The derivation is very simple: Substitute the anzatz in the equation, write down the equations for the coefficients and complex conjugate the equation on $\bar{b}$ to obtain an equation for b.

The next step is to put this system into matrix form and look for eigenvalues and vectors. It is easier at this point to take $\lambda = i\omega$ and then after finding the roots of the characteristic polynomial:
$$ \lambda_{\pm} = -1 \pm \sqrt{-(\alpha + \frac{1}{2}k^2 - 2|\psi_e|^2)^2 +|\psi_e|^4}$$
The eigenvectors can also be found for given values of k and $\alpha$, and this gives the coefficients a and b for the anzatz. This gives the first order correction for the solution $\psi_e$ under a small perturbation.